# Align Elements horizontally, jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I havent much experience on jquery mobile or related mobile UI frameworks, I am finding it difficult to align elements horizontally.

I want to horizontally align text field and select tag. so that they appear inline.

I tried ***data-type="horizontal"*** and ***data-inline="true"***. but they are not working.

Here's the code i am using,

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
      <label for="cs" class="fieldLabel">option 1: </label>
      <select name="cs[param_string_1]" id="cs[param_string_1]" data-inline="true">
          <option>options</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" data-inline="true" style="width:100px" id="cs[param_num_1]" name="cs[param_num_1]"  />  
</div>
```

Comments/Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tom's answer was useful. but that dint work exactly as per the need

I used following to get the required output.

```
   <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td width="30%">
             <select name="cs_abc" class="fieldLabel" style="width: 100%" data-inline="true"  id="cs[abc]">
               <option>...</option>         
             </select>  
             </td>
             <td width="70%">
               <input type="text" id="cs_xyz"  style="width:160px" data-theme="d"  name="cs[xyz]" />
             </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
```

One can use layout grids for this (Refer [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html))

But layout grids may not give precise results, at least in my case i was not getting the needed alignment.

[Some good fiddles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709994/any-way-to-force-two-elements-to-stay-next-to-each-other-on-the-same-row-with-jq) were useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Text inputs & Textareas](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/textinputs/).

It does not support `data-inline` on its own, but you can use `data-role=fieldcontain` instead:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
</div>
```

As far as I can see you can't put multiple inputs next to each other using only jQuery Moblie...

Comment: one can use layout grids also tables can be useful. i solved my problem using tables. if you want you may update your answer. thnx

Comment: @mashit: Layout grids might be a possibility, but tables are wrong because they are semantically meant for data. You could as well have used styled divs to get around the issue.

Comment: can give some example for styled divs?

Comment: just for reference for other users: fieldcontain is deprecated as of version 1.4.0 (http://api.jquerymobile.com/fieldcontain/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div href="#" data-role="button" style="margin:30px;">Adjust</div>
```

> if you want to manipulate just right and left adjustments use `style="margin-left=30px;margin-right=30px;"`

Answer (score 1):

...I am still learning the jQuery Mobile framework myself, so I know it is a pain when you just need to get something done, but you really should try to use what is already built within the framework, especially if you are going to build mobile friendly apps. Do yourself a favor and take the time needed to learn it.

Also, another tip; you need to stay away from using px values for sizing elements as that typically doesn't scale well on mobile devices, em values work best for cross platform use.

I have successfully used something similar to the following code to "inline" text input and select boxes with jqm. if you want the styles to be different - you can add the theme swatch letter after the individual ui-block element so that it looks something like ui-block-b or ui-block-c, etc. This is all documented here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc1/docs/content/content-grids.html

```
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block">
      <label for="cs[ps_1]" class="fieldLabel ui-hidden-accessible">option 1: </label>
      <select name="cs[ps_1]" id="cs[ps_1]" data-mini="true">
        <option>options</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block">
      <input type="text" style="width:10em;" id="cs[pn_1]" name="cs[pn_1]" />
    </div>
  </div><!-- /grid-a -->
```